# Angular 7+ Modularized Frontend

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I would like to create a modularized frontend application, each module must be released independently.

My problem is that I can create angular modules for each frontend module, but I have to build all modules together to make a release.

I want to release modules independently and change versions of modules independently in frontend.

Is there any way to make a dynamically loadable statically builded modules?

Alternative solution is to use iframes what I really don't want. In iframe each modules can be an independent application.

Comment: Our company used to have modularized app, but eventually we gave up, it is just too much trouble to manage module dependency, say, module version mismatch

Comment: Have you tried Angular elements?

Answer (score 1):

You could either release every module as a different library, and implement those libraries in one central app. 
[Angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) might also be a solution: you can define entire modules as a web element, which can then be implemented anywhere you want.